# WebRTC establish specific peerConnection

Tags: google-chrome, p2p, webrtc

I am recently learning webRTC and now I can successfully establish the peerConnection after using getUserMedia and createPeerConnection. But this connection is established randomly, I mean I cannot chose whom I want to connect. 
Now I am thinking to establish the connection with a specific IP address, how to realize this? Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a websocket to connect both peers.

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://yourdomain.com:1337');
```

You need to install a server like node.js. I found this prototype useful:
[Video Conferencing Proto](http://blog.gingertech.net/2012/06/04/video-conferencing-in-html5-webrtc-via-web-sockets/)
After the installation run: `node websocket-server.js`

Did you get the new JSEP protocol to run? I have problems replacing the deprecated ROAP protocol with JSEP.